# How to Change the Default Item Count of Lists (Grids) in the Backend?

Tags: admin, grid, grid-serlization

All the admin grids show - by default - 20 items.

How can this default by increased?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This value is defined in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`, extended by all admin grids. The value is hardcoded in the class, and is not configurable anywhere AFAIK.

To override this value, an event observer could be used, for example on the event `adminhtml_block_html_before`. In the observer method, you could check if the block extends the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`, and set the default value to, say, 50.

The observer method could look like this:

```
public function changeDefaultLimit(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if ($block && $block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid) {
        $block->setDefaultLimit(50);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This could also be done using local.xml (only limitation is that you would have to add two entry for each grid)

E.g changing order sales grid to 100 items

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_index>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
        <action method="setDefaultLimit">
              <limit>100</limit>
      </action> 
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_index>

<adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
        <action method="setDefaultLimit">
              <limit>100</limit>
      </action> 
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to use observer `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before` in my observer then fmrng solution worked perfectly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NameSpace_Admingrids>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </NameSpace_Admingrids>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <admingrids>
                <class>NameSpace_Admingrids_Model</class>
            </admingrids>
        </models>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <admingrids>
                        <class>admingrids/observer</class>
                        <method>changeDefaultLimit</method>
                    </admingrids>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```